# How do I draw transparent polygons with ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, c#, .net, transparency-opacity

How do I draw transparent polygons in ArcObjects? I mean is it possible to set alpha channel?

Comment: While not an arcobjects solution [this GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68130/arcgis-symbology-transparency) might be of interest as it describes trying to set individual polygon alpha values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transparency is not a property of a polygon itself, rather it is a property of the layer containing the polygon (like symbology). Take your polygon data, and store it in an [IFeatureLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/FeatureLayerClass_Class/0012000000sv000000/). From IFeatureLayer, get [ILayerEffects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ILayerEffects_Interface/00120000072m000000/), which is an interface of IFeatureLayer. [Transparency](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Transparency_Property/00120000072v000000/) (0% to 100%) is a property of ILayerEffects.

Also, note this from ESRI documentation:

*When you set Transparency for a FeatureLayer, a TransparencyDisplayFilter is created and applied to the layer. You can accomplish the same effect by manually creating a new TransparencyDisplayFilter using IDisplayFilter, and then assigning it to a layer using
IDisplayFilterManager.*